# JSF 2 f:subview not seeing my changes reflected in the UI

Tags: jsf-2, websphere, facelets

**Update** It appears I have to rebuild/redeploy the app to see the changes.  Anyone know why I have to do this? It's a static .xhtml page.  Coming back to update, looks like I just have to stop/restart the server, not a rebuild.  I was dumb and didn't try that first, mostly because I have to rebuild/deploy often anyways.

I'm working on a **JSF 2** app that uses `f:subviews`.  I'm on one subview where my changes aren't reflected in the UI when I refresh the browser.  I've worked on other subviews where I don't have  this problem.

I have a batch script which copies my .xhtml files into my installed apps folder.  The batch script reports the file is copied over.  It's business as usual... If I drill down into this particular installed app, I see my change in the file.  Again, seems like business as usual.  The change is not reflected in the UI when I refresh, however.

These are simple text changes I'm making, but not seeing.

The problematic subview doesn't appear to be anything special, it's just a p:datatable that's included via a `ui:include` with a couple of parameters for the data and to give it a unique id.  If I replace the p:datatable with just simple text, the "old" table still shows up in the UI when I refresh.  I just can't get any changes in this subview to be reflected in the UI.

Console doesn't throw any errors.

I'm using **WebSphere 7.0**.

Never encountered this problem before.  It isn't a browser caching issue as I can edit other subviews and see those changes when I refresh the page.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which JSF impl/version are you using? Which JSF project stage setting are you using? MyFaces (as by default bundled in WebSphere) is known to cache Facelets files rather agressively when JSF project stage is not set to "Development" (as by default).

Comment: It's JSF 2, project stage looks to be facelets.DEVELOPMENT false in web.xml.  I tend to not think it's caching because why would it be selectively caching files?  I don't have this problem with all subviews. My changes show up in the installed app directory, I clear the browser cache, it's just for some subviews I can not see simple changes I make. I also have not had this issue with other JSF 2 apps here, though this was just updated to JSF 2 and had a bunch of consolidation work done on it, which could be the source, but I can't say one way or the other as that person isn't here now.

Comment: "JSF 2" is just a specification. Again, which JSF implementation and version are you using? There is Mojarra and there is MyFaces. They are in turn available in versions like 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.x, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.x, etc. All I know is that Websphere 7.0 ships by default with some ancient MyFaces version. But it would be as good possible that you upgrade/replaced it youself or so. Anyway, given that you seem to have no utter idea what that means, I'll assume that you're indeed using WebSphere's default JSF impl/version. In that case, just set `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` to `Development`.

Comment: By the way, `facelets.DEVELOPMENT` is specific to Facelets 1.x, which is not part of JSF 2.

Comment: Sorry, it's Mojarra 2.1.22

Comment: We're definitely using JSF 2, if I'm pointing out something like facelets.DEVELOPMENT, it's because I don't know where to look for the project stage and that's what I'm finding, which I think is the answer.  I'm a front-end developer so there's a bit of JSF technical vagueness to me.  That is most likely leftover JSF 1.x in the app.